# SQL: Grouping on a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query where I want to aggregate column `ElementAantal`. However this is the first time I am grouping on columns where there is a subquery `ArtikelInhoud` involved.

Please your advise on how to make the query work.

```
SELECT          
                pl.[Location Code] AS Locatie,
                pl.[Ending Date] AS ProdOrderDatum,
                pl.[Item No_] AS Artikelnr,
                pl.Description AS Artikel,
                pbl.No_ AS Elementnr,
                pbl.Description AS Element,
                SUM(pbl.Quantity * pl.Quantity) AS ElementAantal,   -----> Aggregating this column
                i.[Item Category Code] AS ElementCategorie,
                (
                    SELECT      Value
                    FROM        [$Attribute Specification] att
                    WHERE       [Table ID] = 27 AND Code = 'INH' AND att.[Unique Record Identifier] = i1.[Unique Record Identifier]
                ) AS ArtikelInhoud,
                i.[Gross Weight] AS ElementGewicht,
                v.Name AS Leverancier
FROM            [$Prod_ Order Line] pl
LEFT JOIN       [$Production BOM Line] pbl ON pl.[Production BOM No_] = pbl.[Production BOM No_]
LEFT JOIN       [$Item] i ON pbl.No_ = i.No_
LEFT JOIN       [$Item] i1 ON pl.[Item No_] = i1.No_
LEFT JOIN       [$Vendor] v ON i.[Vendor No_] = v.No_
GROUP BY        pl.[Location Code],
                pl.[Ending Date],
                pl.[Item No_],
                pl.Description,
                pbl.No_,
                pbl.Description,
                i.[Item Category Code],
                (
                    SELECT      Value
                    FROM        [$Attribute Specification] att
                    WHERE       [Table ID] = 27 AND Code = 'INH' AND att.[Unique Record Identifier] = i1.[Unique Record Identifier]
                ),
                i.[Gross Weight],
                v.Name
```

Comment: Why not use a `JOIN` rather than a subquery? But for that subquery, you'd only need to group on `i1.[Unique Record Identifier]`.

Comment: Wrap your query in an outer query and apply GROUP BY to the outer query.